# Insert Ember Component in to a specific DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom, ember.js, appendto

I'm trying to insert an Ember Component into a specific DOM element: `<div id="component"></div>`

I currently have this code:

```
   var App = Ember.Application.create();

   App.NavigationBarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
     tagName: 'nav'
   });
```

And:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
     <h1>Component</h1>
 </script>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an instance of the component then use `appendTo` to append it to an element on the page.  This is not a normal use case, but you can do it.

```
var comp = App.FooBarComponent.create();
comp.appendTo('#someArea');
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yepibibe/1/edit

Comment: Is there a way to do in Ember 3 ?

Answer (score -1):

Or you can create view insted of commponent. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html

Comment: As of Ember 2 the usage of views is discouraged, they are used internally only and components should be used instead

Comment: This answer is from 2014 though. I can't really see the future, sorry.