# How to programmatically insert an Ember component into a div?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, hbs

I am trying to figure out a way to use Ember components as a view template for tooltips. Let me explain this:

I am supposed to create a library to show tooltips in Ember. The content of this tooltip is unknown. It might be very complex or it might be a simple text. The developer is the one who will decide it but the library must offer a way to do it easily. Also, I want to offer this solution in the format of an **Ember modifier** so that the developer would code it something like:

```html
<div {{tooltip foo bar}}>
  Hello World
</div>
```

As the modifier offers a reference to its element it is easy to use the good old JS to create elements and append them to this element. For a simple text it works like a charm and I was able to do it already as shown in the example below, but for complex component it's better to create a component and show it inside the tooltip's container.

```js
// tooltip.js

import { modifier } from 'ember-modifier';
import { isPresent } from '@ember/utils'

export default modifier(function tooltip(element) {
  const content = document.createElement('span')
  content.append('Hi, I am the tooltip\'s text')
  
  element.append(content)
});
```

The problem starts when you want to build a complex view, specially if it's supposed to contain some logic associated.

What I thought is that I could programmatically insert Ember components into the element that is passed as the argument of the modifier function. I can't use the dynamic component helper (`{{component}}`) as it infers that I have to mess with `.hbs` files more than what I am doing already and I can't approach it using the tooltip as a component; I need it to be a modifier.

I looked into this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23378698/4027692) but it doesn't seem to work in Ember 3.8.

Can anybody give me a clue on how do make it happen?
I am using Ember 3.8 and [Ember Modifier@1.0.5](https://github.com/ember-modifier/ember-modifier/tree/v1.0.5)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same technique that either of these use:

1. https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-popperjs
2. https://github.com/CrowdStrike/ember-velcro

They allow for "any content tooltips" by using an external library (popper or floating-ui, depending -- these are important though, because positioning is hard).

The gist is the following:

1. modifier on the "reference" / "hook" element (what you hover over)
2. modifier on the "target" / "popover" / "loop" element
3. some code that communicates between the two modifiers to wait until both are present before rendering the tooltip in the correct location / position.

The key part missing from your original code is that you need two modifiers -- tooltips with complex content are not possible with a single modifier (unless you manually manage element references).

For ember 3.8, I don't know how much you'll be able to do.

- Ember 3.28 is the oldest LTS supported now and is passed its last bugfixes date, and it will step receiving security patches in January -- see: https://emberjs.com/releases/lts/

you may be able to use 2 global modifiers and a service to communicate between them -- but I don't know how that would work when you attempt to have multiple tooltips / popovers on the screen at the same time.

---

The minimum ember version you need to use the two addons linked above is 3.27.

*Personally*, it's well worth the upgrade, as staying up to date is generally easier than leap frogging years at a time (because you have the community doing upgrades with you) -- and shiny stuff is fun :)